# Return key press not reflecting the changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have content editable td in my html table. I can change text here and the changes are reflected to database only if I click somewhere in the page using mouse. I want the data to get reflected on the return key press on the keyboard

```
 <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" data-old_value="<?php echo $rows1["coin_id"]; ?>" onBlur="saveInlineEdit1(this,'coin_id','<?php echo $rows1["coin_id"]; ?>','<?php echo $userRow['userId']; ?>')"><?php echo $rows1["coin_id"]; ?></td>
```

Now I detect a return key press using following jquery script,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#enterit').on('keydown', 'td', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).click();
        }
}); });
```

This only detects the return key press. I want the return key press action to perform the action that the anywhere click on the page by mouse does.

To be simple, I want something like that happens with phpmyAdmin. Let the scenario be that you want to edit data of any field in the database table. You just click on the data, edit it and press return to save the changes. I want this same functionality as in phpmyAdmin in my html table.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: so basically you are saying $(this).click() isnt working?

Comment: yes ...its detects return key but no action on the page

Comment: What are you expecting? What action you want to happen? .click() will execute the click function on the td element.

Comment: After editing the text in a table cell, if i click somewhere on the page  using mouse the td field goes blur and sends the edited text to my database. Now i want this happen when return key is pressed

Comment: to be simple... the td must blur on return key press

Comment: Please provide a fiddle. I just tried by completing your code with the missing parts (i.e. what is `enterit`), and the function `highlightEdit` is called when pressing enter.

Comment: if clicking anywhere on the page does the action, try $('body').click();

Comment: $('body').click(); not working...

Comment: @trincot  onBlur() is only what I need... I have removed my onClick()... enterit is div id for the whole table. So if any return key is pressed in that div its get detected. Its working fine. After detecting I want it to blur the td field..

Comment: Could you provide us with a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#enterit').on('keydown', 'td', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).blur();
        }
}); });
```

$(this).blur(); worked fine.